# Creating an exposed filter on a view as a list with taxonomy terms

Tags: taxonomy-terms, views

I have categories of photographs and each photograph is categorised. So to expose the filter to the anonymous user they can click on a category and it shows that categories images.

How would I replace the select list or auto complete exposed filter with this so I can then style the list as a horizontal small menu above the view?

Answer (score 0):

[Better Exposed Filters](https://www.drupal.org/project/better_exposed_filters) would be helpful for that.  It allows you to replace the select/autocomplete with normal anchors that can be styled however you prefer.

After installing and enabling BEF, add your exposed filter and save it (you only have the standard options at this point).  Then, go to the views advanced settings and change "Exposed form style" to Better Exposed Filters.  Then you will have a BEF Settings option, this is where you will see the options below.

**Advanced settings:**

[image]

**This is the setting you're looking for:**

[image]

Comment: I don't seem to have this option in my Exposed Filter settings when adding the filter Content: Has taxonomy terms (with depth). I'm using taxonomy terms to filter and trying to expose this.

Comment: I've added some more specific details to the answer.  In short, those options are available under the BEF settings rather than the exposed filter settings.